# File object from URL with http or https

Tags: java, file, url

Can be obtain a File object from URL? I try something like

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
File file = Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile();
```

but it obtained exception

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "http" not installed
```

or https... depending on the protocol used. Assume that urlString contain a valid address.

Exist an altenative to get it the File object from URL or I'm on wrong way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.nio.file.Path for URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783523/java-nio-file-path-for-urls)

Comment: No.  Only `file:` URLs represent files on the host system.  Are you sure you need a File?  You can read from a URL with its [openStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open a connection to the URL, start getting the bytes the server is sending you, and save them to a file.

## Using Java NIO

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

## Using Apache Common IO

Another approach is to use the apache [common io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)) library, and you can do it like this:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
File file = new File("filename.html");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use URI.getPath() before passing it to Paths.get()

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
File file = Paths.get(url.toURI().getPath()).toFile();
```